# Delphi XE6, VCL, Firemonkey, Appmethod

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Embarcadero recently launched Appmethod, a kind of pay as you go IDE for mobile development based on Delphi XE5 IDE and Firemonkey framework. When asking a question about Appmethod what tag should I use keeping in mind it's the FMX framework but the IDE is appmethod and not Delphi XE5 or Rad Studio? Should there be a Tag for Appmethod?

Comment: If the question is IDE-specific, then yes, an Appmethod tag would be appropriate. If the question applies generally to the language/framework, regardless of which IDE you're using, then it seems unnecessary to include an Appmethod tag.

Comment: I agree - I don't know if you've used Appmethod but the IDE is very much identical to your run of the mill XE3-XE6 IDE (obviously one or two omissions of features etc...), I've only been coding and getting to know Appmethod so I'm not too sure that when you get down to the "Nitty Gritty" of it it is maybe different?

Comment: Never used any of it, that's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. I don't consider myself qualified to answer, I can just say generally what I would do.

Comment: NP, thanks for the input none the less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update* AppMethod, which was just a different name and licensing model for RAD Studio, has been discontinued and no longer even exists as an option (2016+).  It's in the bad ideas dumpster now.

Original answer:

AppMethod is a different licensing option for the same RAD Studio IDE, so tagging your questions AppMethod is just going to restrict who views it.  Any question you could possibly ask about AppMethod is equally applicable under the combined tag of "firemonkey" (the framework) and either "delphi" or "c++builder", the language.   The IDE used by AppMethod is RAD Studio, but nobody tags anything Rad Studio because it never matters.  So, AppMethod, is a different name, and a different license, that is immaterial to most StackOverflow user's purposes. No offense to Embarcadero, I rather like AppMethod and I'm glad it exists. My view is, there's no POINT tagging your question as AppMethod.